# php result within a date range

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am an absolute newbie and still working out the kinks. So spare me if the code looks amateurish.

I have this form.html

The user enters the date range.

```
      form action="report.php" method="post"
           FROM DATE <input type="DATE" class="textarea" name="dateStart"><br> </br>
            TO DATE <input type="DATE" class="textarea" name="dateEnd">
            <input type="submit" class="textarea">
             </form>
```

This gets processed in Report.php now report.php looks like this:

```
             php
              $_POST["dater"]=$date;
              $con=mysqli_connect("LOCALHOST","xxxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxx"); 
              // Check connection
              if (mysqli_connect_errno())
               {
             echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }

           $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `xxxxxxx` 
            dater);


          echo "<table border='1'>
          <tr>
        <th>DATE</th>
        <th>MBM</th>
        <th>bulkTank</th>
        <th>bagsAt40</th>
```

";

```
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {
          echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['bulkTank'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['bagsAt40'] . "</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";
```

I have no clue what to do next....
its not working, i tried a few things but how can I echo the result within a specific date range. Thanks!

New edit ----
This is what the new code looks like... Form
     
          START DATE 
 
            END DATE

```
     Report.php

       <?php
           $date=$_POST["dateStart"];
                 $con=mysqli_connect("LOCALHOST","XXXXXXX","++++++","XXXXXX"); 
                // Check connection
                if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                 {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                      }

                           $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `WeeklyStockTake` 
                           WHERE dateColumn=$date);


                             echo "<table border='1'>   <!--line 32 starts here--!>
                                       <tr>
                                        <th>DATE</th>
                                           <th>MBM</th>
                                          <th>bulkTank</th>
                                              <th>bagsAt40</th>
```

-----If I process it now I get this error - 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/simples2/public_html/test/report.php on line 32 (I have commented above as to where it starts)
How to I declare the end date?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What does the table structure look like with regards to the date columns? Is there just one date column or are there two, like a start and end date?

Comment: "It's not working": We'll be better able to help if you can provide some more information. You can add in some basic error testing at each step by e.g. <pre>print_r($result)</pre>. Is it failing at the mysqli call stage, not returning anything (or null/false) or is the php throwing an error?

Comment: Thanks guys, I will start putting up the errors. The database just has one column i.e. date. Should it have more columns? Thanks and regards!

Comment: It gives me "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/simples2/public_html/test/report.php on line 32" This is what starts at echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>DATE</th>
<th>MBM</th>
<th>bulkTank</th>
<th>bagsAt40</th>
<th>caketank25</th>
<th>loadoutTanks53</th>
<th>containers20</th>
<th>tallow</th>

Comment: you didn't close the quote at row with sql query: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `xxxxxxx` 
            dater); You should finish with dater");, Same for Report.php

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if its a typo but php should be `<?php`

```
$_POST["dater"]=$date
```

This should be

```
$date=$_POST["dateStart"]
```

Also you should add a POST for dateEnd also

The query should be more like:

```
SELECT * FROM `xxxxxxx` WHERE dateColumn<=$date
```

Comment: Add more details regarding your table.

Comment: Thanks for that but how will it know where to stop. DO I need to declare the end date.....then will WHERE change to start and end date?

Comment: Something like that,depends how the date column or columns are in your table,that's why I asked for details.

Comment: There is just one column in the database that is date.

Comment: What is column type - datetime, timestamp, int, varchar?